# Imageview Gets Blurred

Tags: android

I have uploaded an image using Intent from gallery into an imageveiw. But the image gets blured, once the page is refreshed it is shown without getting blurred. How to avoid blurring??

```
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String tempPath = home.getPath(selectedImageUri, getActivity());
            final BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            btmapOptions.inSampleSize = 8;
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrease `btmapOptions.inSampleSize = 8;` to something smaller, maybe 4?
(`btmapOptions.inSampleSize = 4;`).

Also set `scaleType` on your `ImageView` to `centerInside` or `centerCrop`

Comment: I set scale type to FIT XY. But once the page is reloaded i get the image without blurring. why it is??

Comment: If you set `fitXY` you are forcing bitmap to scale. In your case it may be not proportional scale and additionally input image could be to small. 
Where do you set scale type? Please do it just in XML and remove all occurrences from code. This way you will be sure it's set properly.